# Write efficient java code and oracle query

Tags: java

Design a system java same as relational database. 
For example, 
You Have employee table as below:

```
ID | Name | Manager | Salary
```

Now you can execute queries like :

```
select * from Employee where ID= ' something'

select * from Employee where Name= ' something'

select * from Employee where Name= ' something'
```

In same way you have a class Employee as bellow:

```
 class Employee{
 String ID;
 String Name;
 String Salary;
 String Manager;
 }
```

Now I want to query on this class as same as the SQL queries above, 
How can I do it efficiently?

The code should be optimized on time complexity and space complexity.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far. What have you tried ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework dump.

Comment: @chrylis You are free to vote how you want, but I would read chiastic-security's answer on this meta question to perhaps change your mind for future homework-no-personal-effort questions. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274748/424903

Comment: @Gimby That answer suggests not using "too broad" or "unclear" inappropriately for no-effort close votes, which I took the time to type out an explanation to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have collections like `List` or `Set` which could be thought of as a Table or Rows.

You also have Map which acts like an unique index, and NavigableMap which works like a unique sorted index.  There is also MultiMap which is like a non-unique index.